# Сортировка пользователей firebase

Tags: android, сортировка, firebase, уведомления, push-уведомления

Есть такая задача. Пользователь запускает приложение и первым делом он выбирает свой город. Нужно, чтобы как-то в firebase пользователи делились на города, а потом этим группам рассылались push уведомления. Каждой группе по отдельности. Как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала, вам понадобится Database от Firebase. Подробнее [тут](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/).
В базу данных вам будет нужно записывать город пользователя и его [токен регистрации FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/android/console-device#access_the_registration_token), с помощью которого можно будет послать уведомление на конкретное устройство.

Как это будет происходить: вы получаете все токены пользователей конкретного города из базы данных, затем по этим токенам отправляете уведомления с помощью Firebase notifications.

---

P.S Я не пользовался уведомлениями от Firebase, но я думаю, что это реализуемо примерно таким способом.

Comment: Спасибо! А как можно из базы данных все токены обработать сразу? То есть, чтобы все токены города взять и им сразу отправить уведомление

Comment: @Bullshit для этого нужно обрабатывать токены программно. Почитайте это http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37398898/firebase-notifications-through-server-side-code